# Property 'create' is missing in type '{ CKSource: {}; }' but required in type 'EditorConstructor'

Tags: javascript, angular, ckeditor5, angular13

[image]

I am trying to import a custom build of CKEditor 5. I follow the same way as in the [documentions](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/angular.html#using-a-custom-ckeditor-5-build). anyone have an idea about it?

Comment: Did you import the module into your module where this component is declared?

Comment: Yes, I import that already.

Comment: Can you try put [(ngModel)]="model.editorData" in this field?

Comment: No, still it's not working, same error